# Php drop box with Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to populate PHP drop box from Oracle table. But it shows the empty drop box. Due to this drop box other submit buttons do not work as well when I remove this drop box other submit buttons work fine. Please experts help me out to resolve this as I have to deliver this in couple of days. Following is the code for dropbox:

```
<form action="" method="post" style="display: inline;"> 
    <select name="Date" onchange="this.form.submit()"><option value="">Select an Employee</option> 
    <?php 
    $rs = ("select DISTINCT TRANSACTION_DATE from RTLOGS_BO_CO_FAILED"); 
    $sql=$db->Execute($rs);
    while ($at = $sql->FetchRow()) { 
        //echo'<option value="'.$at'">'.$at'</option>';
        echo"<option value=\"unit1\">" . $at['TRANSACTION_DATE'] . "      </option>";
     } 
     ?> 
     </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your sql select statement so that it returns a value to display and a value behind

```
select DISTINCT TRANSACTION_DATE AS SHOW_DATE, TRANSACTION_DATE 
from RTLOGS_BO_CO_FAILED
order by TRANSACTION_DATE
```

Note the use of the alias for your distinct transaction date.  Some lists like a clear name for the object.

Comment: Thanks! My issue has been resolved. Problem was in distinct transaction_date which was actually not a date but a character value.